# AWS RDS Error: Failed to retrieve account attributes, certain console functions may be impaired

Tags: amazon-web-services, relational-database, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS. I am utilizing their free Tier which includes the Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS). According to [them](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/), this free tier consist of the following:

- 750 hours of Amazon RDS Single-AZ db.t2.micro Instance usage
- 20 GB of DB Storage
- 10 million I/Os
- 20 GB of backup storage

I have signed up and gave my information, including payment method and even "charge" me $1 (for verification).

When I go to RDS Dashboard, I always get this error...

> Failed to retrieve account attributes, certain console functions may
>   be impaired.

And if I continue, I get this...

> An unexpected error occurred. You may attempt to proceed, but launch
>   wizard functionality may be impaired.

I tried researching ways to go about this. There are a few questions posted on their Discussion Forums regarding this, but they are still unanswered.

Can someone please help me regarding this error? Please let me know as I really need this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try changing the location to a different region and see if it works?

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. :(

Comment: Are you trying as master user of the account? or are you trying as an IAM user?

Comment: IAM user. Didn't get to make the master user account because it is on the Step 2 (Specify DB Details) Step in the RDS which is where I get the Error: 'An unexpected error occurred. You may attempt to proceed, but launch wizard functionality may be impaired.'

Comment: By master user I meant the Root Account for AWS? So you created a IAM user what policy did you gave the IAM user?

Comment: Sorry. I am new to this. I gave the AdministratorAccess policy.

Comment: Try one thing login using the root account and try creating the RDS and see if gets created?

Comment: I got the same result.

Comment: Ok then there is issue with your AWS account contact customer support as root account has all the privileges for the AWS resources.

Comment: Note also, they probably did not actually "charge" you $1. It's just an authorization hold that will time out and be canceled in 3-5 days.  That's a common mechanism for verifying that a card is legitimate and not lost or stolen.

Comment: For me it works after ~2 hr - and in India it is INR 2, not $1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because of $$$. They really want to charge you the $1 auth fee before you are allowed to do anything. Takes 2-8 hours for new accounts.

http://www.texient.com/2016/09/failed-to-retrieve-account-attributes-with-new-aws-account.html

Answer (score -1):

It happened to me because of the payment method problem.
I added my card info but there was not the minimum 1$ in the bank account.
So first check your bank account balance, then go to your payment method and press edit. you can edit some parts of the address for example. Just make sure that you have changed something. Then save the new changes. the problem is going to be solved automatically.